# Verilog loop sequentially for each iteration of the loop

Tags: loops, asynchronous, verilog, sequential

I have created a module that is this:

```
module testX(input [6:0]n, input [6:0]offset, output result);
```

I want to run this module increasing the offset until result returns a specific condition.  When I use a loop, the code is compiled so all of the iterations run at the same time like normally synthesized code.

I want to make testX use all the resources of the FPGA and then by changing the offset loop it multiple times in order to make a massive parallel application.

I understand that loops are not to be used like this according to [this source](https://www.nandland.com/articles/synthesizable-vs-non-synthesizable-code-fpga-asic.html), so how would I accomplish something like this?  In a normal programming language, I would just do something like this:

```
while result==0
   testX(n,offset,result)
   offset=offset+C
end while
```

Another side question is how would I know then the testX operation is complete?  Would I need a status variable to indicate it was finished and to change the offset when I saw that the status changed?

Note: This could probably be done with a clock and always statement also, but I am looking for a asynchronous method.

Comment: A Verilog module is not a SW function; you do not run it; you cannot "call" it from within a loop. A Verilog module is a piece of HW; it exists for all time.

Comment: I under stand that.  My goal if to feed different offsets into my module, and look at the result pin to see if it got a result, and output that to a pin.

Comment: In this way, the testX would always exist, but an adder would increment offset as it would continue to loop.

Comment: I started writing up an answer, but then realised I still don't understand your problem. I was going to suggest instantiating many copies of testX inside a generate loop, but you say that testX takes all the resources of the FPGA, so there can only be one instance. In which case, it needs to be time-multiplexed, but then you say you want to make it asynchronous. (Do you mean "combinational" rather than "asynchronous"?)

Comment: What I mean by asynchronous is that as soon as the operations in testX finish, it either changes the clock or the offset variable so there is no time waiting for a clock.  With Greg's answer he says it would not function properly doing this.

Answer (score 1):

You need to time-plex the change to `offset` like below. Hardware will not function properly with complex asynchronous feedback.

```
always @(posedge clk) begin // time-plexing
  if (result==0) begin
     offset <= offset+C; // inside a procedural block, non-blocking assignment
  end
end

testX(n,offset,result); // outside any procedural block
```